# Can you provide arguments to a top level org-babel block for execution?

Tags: org-babel

Given an org-babel for a "top-level" file, one that will generate code to be executed with command line arguments:

```
#+name: main
#+begin_src rust :tangle main.rs
fn main() {
  let argv = std::env::args().collect()
  ....
}
#+end
```

If you try to execute the block with `org-babel-execute-maybe`, the code does not receive any command line argument.

Is there a way to specify arguments as `<switch>` or`<header-argument>` to the code block ?

I would have expected something similar to the `:dir` header arguments, and tried various things (`:args`, `:arguments`, `:input`, etc...)

Comment: It depends on the language; e.g. [C/C++/D](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html#orgc62d39b) provide a `:cmdline` header argument for exactly this purpose. I don't know if the Rust implementation provides that (if it does, it's likely to use the same header argument - at least I would hope so!) but the Rust backend is not documented on Worg apparently.

Comment: The commentary at the top of `ob-rust.el` says that `:args` is supported: `Much of this is modeled after 'ob-C'.  Just like the 'ob-C', you can specify
 :flags headers when compiling with the "rust run" command.  Unlike 'ob-C', you
can also specify :args which can be a list of arguments to pass to the
binary.`

Comment: Simply adding `:args 3` to the block header does not work. I created an issue.